# What does the the output of following code snippet mean?

Tags: python

code: print(type(ValueError))
output: `<class 'type'>`

what does class 'type' mean!
I just don't understand it?

Comment: The `type` function returns a `type` object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type function returns a `type` object that express the type of the object passed as argument, to get the type of an object only use `type(ValueError)`

Answer (score 0):

Objects have specific types (classes) associated with them.

`"henlo"` is a `str` type.

`10` is an `int` type.

`["henlo", "goodbye"]` is a `list` type.

and etc.

The `ValueError` exception just has the class of `type`. There's nothing else to it.